# When should I guard against null?

Tags: c#

When should I guard against `null` arguments? Ideally, I would guard against `null` everywhere, but that gets very bloated and tedious. I also note that people aren't putting guards in things like `AsyncCallback`s.

To keep from annoying other people with lots of unidiomatic code, is there any accepted standard as to where I should guard against `null`?

Thanks.

Comment: I put them everywhere where I consider `null` to be an invalid argument.

Comment: You might be interested in this question on the programmers sister site: [Should one check for null if he does not expect null?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/147480/should-one-check-for-null-if-he-does-not-expect-null/147483)

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a standard - would it be appropriate for someone to make the question community wiki?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One approach which I have used a lot is the [null object pattern.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern)
For example, if a have a factory class which returns different implementations of an interface based on an argument, and the provided argument is not mapped to any of the implementations, I would return a  NullObject,
e.g.

```
   public interface IFoo{
         void Bar();
   }
   public class NullFoo{
       public void Bar(){
          //null behaviour 
       }
   }
   public class FooFactory{
        public IFoo CreateFoo(int i){
              switch(i){
                  case 1:
                  return new OneFoo();
                  break;
                  case 2:
                  return new TwoFoo();
                  break;
                  default:
                  return new NullFoo();
                  break;
              }
        } 
   }
```

When I want get an `IFoo` from `CreateFoo`, I don't have to check whether the returned object is null.

Obviously, this is just one of the many approaches. There is no "one size fits all" since null can mean different things.

Another way to guard against null arguments is to use [CodeContract preconditions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee236408.aspx#id0070015).
e.g.

```
  public void Foo(Bar x){
      Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>( x != null, "x" );
      //access x
  }
```

Using Code Contracts allows you to run static code analysis against your code and catch bugs such as `Foo(null)`. ([more here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh335064.aspx))

One more why to do it would be to use a very simple generic extension method:

```
public static class Ex
{
    public static void EnsureNotNull<T>(this T t, string argName) where T:class
    {
        if(t == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(argName);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can check your arguments like this:

```
 public void Foo(Bar x, Bar y){
     x.EnsureNotNull("x");
     y.EnsureNotNull("y");
 }
```

Comment: The null object pattern only makes sense in some cases - just those where it isn't mission-critical for your object to actually do something.  Failing loud and failing early is definitely preferable in  most situations.  You'll still have to explicitly check for null in cases where you are accepting an argument from user code unless you can be absolutely sure the value passed in comes from a return value from your API.  Great pattern where appropriate, tho :)

Comment: +1 for good information.  I don't think this addresses the entire question, but it is still very useful information.

Comment: On your code example the `NullFoo` class must implement the `IFoo` interface. I tried to edit the answer to fix that but my edit was rejected.

Answer (score 5):

> When should I guard against null arguments?

I will assume you're talking about null arguments passed to public methods or constructors of code you've written.  Note that you also might have to "guard" against null whenever you call any external dependency that might return null, unless your code can gracefully handle those cases.

You should guard against null in any **public** method (including constructors and property setters) that you expose to a user where the null value doesn't have a useful and explicit meaning.  If a null value doesn't mean something special to your code (e.g. end of array, "unknown", etc) then you should not accept that value, and should throw an `ArgumentNullException` instead.

This rule isn't unique to `null` either.  You should always check arguments passed to your public methods.

For example, say you are writing some sort of web service method that does takes a user Id, and does something to a user (e.g. delete them).  You should verify that it is a valid user Id before your method does anything else with that user.  Another example is if you are writing a public method that takes an index to a collection or array.  You should check up front that the index is within the allowed range - that the index isn't bigger than the collection, or less than zero.

> I also note that people aren't putting guards in things like AsyncCallbacks.

If you know that your method pre-conditions are vigilantly kept by the arguments passed to your methods (because you throw exceptions if they aren't), then you are free to skip these checks in your private and internal methods, or private and internal classes.

But as you pointed out, you must still be careful not to trust any return value from an API you didn't write, or any value passed in to your callback methods.  Treat them as "dirty", and assume they can be null or invalid values.

> that gets very bloated and tedious

Specifying and keeping track of pre-conditions for your public methods isn't bloat - it is compiled documentation.  It is how you make sure your code is *right*.  It is how users of your code are told up front that they did something wrong.  Letting this fail in the middle of your method (or maybe in another method in some vaguely related class) makes it that much harder to debug your issue.

This may not seem like a big deal now.  But once you start getting complaints from customers with a `NullReferenceException` 5 levels down in your stack, 20 method calls later, then I think you'll start to see the benefits :)

> To keep from annoying other people with lots of unidiomatic code, is there any accepted standard as to where I should guard against null?

Typically people just write `if ... throw` code at the top of their method.  This is the most idiomatic syntax, and very easy to understand even for beginners.  Sort of like parens in [Lisp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_(programming_language)), once you're to used that pattern you are able to skim it very quickly, without thinking about it.

You could make it faster to write these checks by using Visual Studio [Code Snippets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165392(v=vs.80).aspx).

You could shorten this code a little by using or building some shared code that supports assertion syntax.  Instead of `if ... throw` syntax, you would write a line like `Assert.NotNull(arg1, "arg1");`.  If you want some inspiration you could look at the [NUnit](http://www.nunit.org/) framework's [assertions](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=assertions&r=2.6) and [constraints](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=constraintModel&r=2.6).

You might also want to look into the [Code Contracts API](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/).  It is designed for checking pre-conditions, post-conditions, and invariants (which are the formal names for these "guard conditions").  It can also move some of this verification from run time to compile time, so you can find out you've made mistakes before even running your program.  I haven't really looked at it, but it might also give you more concise syntax.  *Edit: Also see [Pencho Ilchev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10677760/232593) for a short example of using part of this API*.

Answer (score 1):

Null checking for public APIs are a must.  It's easier (and safer) for developers if they know off the bat that they have an error due to a null parameter rather than trying to debug some obscure other exception as a result of that null parameter.

Internally, constructors are a good place to check for nulls for the same reason - it's easier to catch it in the constructor than it is when you call a method on the class.

Some argue that it's good to check everywhere, but I tend to think that it makes more code to sift through when actually reading the code.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes I make a `Preconditions` class which contains static methods for checking some common method preconditions, i.e. a `null` argument -- something like this for example:

```
public static <T> T checkNull(T arg) {
    if (arg == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    return arg;
}
```

This keeps your code a little cleaner.

As far as *where* you should check for `null`, it should be done wherever it's not a valid value.

**Edit**

Noticed this question was tagged as C#, but you get the idea...

Comment: Nitpick: I'd rather throw a `ArgumentNullException`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about method arguments, you have a choice. You can check the arguments and throw `ArgumentNullException`, or you can ignore the check and have something else throw `NullReferenceException` further down the line. The risk you run with not checking the arguments is that your code might change some global state before the `NullReferenceException` is thrown, leaving the program in an unknown state.

In general, it's probably better to check the arguments and document that your method throws `ArgumentNullException`. Yes, it's a little more work and it can be annoying to wade through those checks at the beginning of a method. You have to ask yourself if the more robust code that you get in exchange is a good tradeoff.

See [This link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2004/07/11/180315.aspx) for a good discussion of this issue.

Comment: Another good reason to check arguments is this: whatever exception may happen later -- possibly several calls down in the call stack -- may not help the developer who is calling your code.  It will not be clear whether that exception was the result of a null argument to your method, or of a bug in *your* code.  Fail fast.